# Python stops responding when I run the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, convolution

I am learning image processing using convolution and without using and predefined functions. While searching for the code for the same I came across a code in medium which fulfills the requirement that I was looking for i.e. image processing using convolution without the help of any predefined functions. After running the code I always get the message python has stopped responding. I tried to find the reason but I couldn't get it. The image that I want gets saved into my system but when the code the tries to open it python stops working. No error message is displayed. The problem only occurs when I use   `cv2.imshow(r'C:\Users\Nampoothiri\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\2DConvolved.jpg', output)`

I tried opening the image using

```
im = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Nampoothiri\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\2DConvolved.jpg')
    im.show()
```

the code works fine.
The following is the code:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

def processImage(image):
    image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Nampoothiri\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\Girrafe.jpg') 
    image = cv2.cvtColor(src=image, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (183,275))
    return image



def convolve2D(image, kernel, padding=0, strides=1):
    # Cross Correlation
    kernel = np.flipud(np.fliplr(kernel))

    # Gather Shapes of Kernel + Image + Padding
    xKernShape = kernel.shape[0]
    yKernShape = kernel.shape[1]
    xImgShape = image.shape[0]
    yImgShape = image.shape[1]

    # Shape of Output Convolution
    xOutput = int(((xImgShape - xKernShape + 2 * padding) / strides) + 1)
    yOutput = int(((yImgShape - yKernShape + 2 * padding) / strides) + 1)
    output = np.zeros((xOutput, yOutput))

    # Apply Equal Padding to All Sides
    if padding != 0:
        imagePadded = np.zeros((image.shape[0] + padding*2, image.shape[1] + padding*2))
        imagePadded[int(padding):int(-1 * padding), int(padding):int(-1 * padding)] = image
        print(imagePadded)
    else:
        imagePadded = image

    # Iterate through image
    for y in range(image.shape[1]):
        # Exit Convolution
        if y > image.shape[1] - yKernShape:
            break
        # Only Convolve if y has gone down by the specified Strides
        if y % strides == 0:
            for x in range(image.shape[0]):
                # Go to next row once kernel is out of bounds
                if x > image.shape[0] - xKernShape:
                    break
                try:
                    # Only Convolve if x has moved by the specified Strides
                    if x % strides == 0:
                        output[x, y] = (kernel * imagePadded[x: x + xKernShape, y: y + yKernShape]).sum()
                except:
                    break

    return output
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Grayscale Image
    image = processImage('Image.jpeg')

    # Edge Detection Kernel
    kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 8, -1], [-1, -1, -1]])

    # Convolve and Save Output
    output = convolve2D(image, kernel, padding=2)
    cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Nampoothiri\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\2DConvolved.jpg', output)
    cv2.imshow(r'C:\Users\Nampoothiri\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\2DConvolved.jpg', output)
```

The input image [image: input image of a giraffe]

Comment: Hard to properly debug without the input image. Try adding `cv2.waitKey(0)` after `cv2.imshow`, you should see the displayed image.

Comment: No problem, my man.